# Not able to remove a list of items from a main list in java

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String OptionId = "111, 112, 113, 114, 115";

    List<String> fullList = Arrays.asList(OptionId.split(","));
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("fullList: " + fullList.toString());

    List<String> subItems = fullList.subList(0, 3);

    System.out.println("subItems: " + subItems);

    for (String s : fullList) {
        String strs[] = new String[2];

        if (subItems.contains(s) 
               || subItems.contains(strs[0]) 
               || subItems.contains(strs[1])) {
            values.add(s);                      // save the value to a list
        }
    }
    System.out.println("values: " + values);

    fullList.remove(values);

    System.out.println("fullList: " + fullList);

}
```

As per my knowledge, the final full list should have only [114, 115]. But its not removed the items present in the sublist.

I have also tried the below code.
    fullList.removeAll(values);

But it throws the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(AbstractCollection.java:376)
at com.tesco.rangeplan.client.Test.main(Test.java:32)
```

I need the output as below:

```
fullList: [114,  115]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.
So the size being fixed you cannot add or remove elements.
Wrap it into a `ArrayList` to prevent this limitation :

```
List<String> fullList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(OptionId.split(",")));
```

As alternative you could also do :

```
List<String> fullList = Arrays.stream(OptionId.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that you invoke `remove(Object)` with as param a `List<String>`. 
It will remove nothing as this method allows to remove the element passed to and actually no `List` is contained in a `List` of `String`.  Instead of use `removeAll(Collection<?>)` that accepts a collection as parameter.

Comment: I have modified as suggested above. But still my final output is: fullList: [111,  112,  113,  114,  115]

Comment: You invoke remove() with as param a List of String instead of a String. Use rather removeAll(). I updated.

Answer (score 0):

You specific error `UnsupportedOperationException` is because you are using `Arrays.asList` which returns a fixed sized List. You can not add / remove from it. That's why it throws the exception.

Create the `ArrayList` and add the items to it. By the way the line

`String strs[] = new String[2];` and your follow equals checks will always result in false, since there is nothing in it. Also if you split by `,` you should also `trim()` it or else you have whitespaces with your current example.

Comment: Since `set` is implemented, it isn't really immutable.

Comment: @lexicore true.